# Migrating from URLSession to Alamofire 4.3 in Swift 3, Encoding issue

Tags: swift, post, alamofire

What is the equivalent code of the following in `Alamofire 4.3`,`Swift 3`?

```
let baseUrl = "https://hiddenWebsite.com/api/index_load"
let url = URL(string: baseUrl)
let authObj = ["owner_id": "361900", "auth_key": "f408634ac1e14c08eebce46c34ab9db2", "device": "2", "version": "2.1.16"]
let infoObj = ["case": "feeds", "feeds_call_type": "init", "feed_type": "", "load_next_from": "1"]

let infoJSONData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: infoObj)
let infoStr = "info" + "=" + String(data: infoJSONData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!

let authJSONData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: authObj)
let authStr = "auth" +  "=" + String(data: authJSONData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!

let combinedStr = infoStr  +  "&" + authStr
let reqdat = combinedStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = reqdat
let defaultSession = URLSession.shared
defaultSession.dataTask(
    with: request,
    completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error while fetching data: \(error)")
            return
        }
        guard let data = data,
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(
                with: data,
                options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
            else {
                print("Nil data received")
                return
        }
        print(json)
}).resume()
```

I'm currently migrating from Apple's URLSession to Alamofire, but stuck at this point. I think this has something to do with encodingParameter.
This is my failed attempt. I also tried with URLEncoding.httpbody but didn't work.

```
    let baseUrl = "https://hiddenWebsite.com/api/index_load"
    let masterParameter = [
        "auth": ["owner_id": "361900",
                 "auth_key": "f408634ac1e14c08eebce46c34ab9db2",
                 "device": "2",
                 "version": "2.1.16"],
        "info": ["case": "feeds",
                 "feeds_call_type": "init",
                 "feed_type": "",
                 "load_next_from": "1"]
    ]
    Alamofire.request(baseUrl, method: .post, parameters: masterParameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in

        print(response)
    }
```

The working postman equivalent of this looks like
[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLH6J.png)

Answer (score 0):

The encoding you are using it not valid JSON. Therefore, you cannot use `JSON.default` as your encoding type because it will encode your `masterParameter` dictionary as a valid JSON dictionary.

Instead, you either need to build your `URLRequest` manually as you have done in your first example and use the `Alamofire.request(urlRequest)` API, or you can create your own [`ParameterEncoding`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#custom-encoding) where you pass your data into it then encode the `URLRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [cnoon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1342462/cnoon) for answering. The following code solved the issue:

```
public enum JSONError: Error {
    case serializing(String)
    case encoding
}

extension String: ParameterEncoding {
    public func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var request = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()
        request.httpBody = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        return request
    }
}

let encodedStr = try getEncodedString(parameters: masterParameter)
Alamofire.request(baseUrl, method: .post, parameters: [:], encoding: encodedStr).responseJSON { response in
        print(response)
}
```

where getEncodedString(parameters:) is defined as:

```
func getEncodedString(parameters: Parameters) throws -> String {

        var encodedStr = ""
        for (key, value) in parameters {

            let jsonData: Data
            do {
                jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value)
            }
            catch(let error) {
                throw JSONError.serializing(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            guard let encodedJsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) else {
                throw JSONError.encoding
            }
            let keyValueStr = key + "=" + encodedJsonString
            encodedStr += keyValueStr + "&"
        }
        if encodedStr.characters.last == "&" {
            encodedStr.remove(at: encodedStr.index(before: encodedStr.endIndex))
        }

        return encodedStr
    }
```